# noClassdeffounderror with external jar when running code from a different location

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and was trying to test my code on another machine but am running to the above error.  I've looked at youtube videos, read forums(and SO) but still can't get this to work.

I basically wrote some code on my mac using eclipse that referenced an external jar file.  I have that jar in my lib folder and have added it to my build path in Eclipse via right-click "Build Path -> Add to Build Path".  The code works fine on my laptop.

But when I try to run it from a linux command line, I get the above error.  I am taking the code from eclipse and copying it to a file(first_try.java) and then run this commands:

```
CLASSPATH=./jedis-2.0.0.jar;export CLASSPATH 
javac first_try.java 
java -classpath . first_try
```

but then I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Jedis`   I downloaded the program via wget and checked permissions and tried different variations. There was a similar question I found(out of the many related ones) that had a similar context as mine but it worked for the user to just type java filename (which is not working for me)

I am learning a bit of java code but have never been successful at running external jars.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to permanently fix it(ideally I want to write code locally and then copy it and test it on another machine like this)?

Or is there a better way to deploy code that depends on third party jars to other systems?

Comment: Try this `javac -cp ./jedis-2.0.0.jar first_try.java` and than `java -cp .: ./jedis-2.0.0.jar first_try`.

Comment: @RanRag Exact same error as above.

Comment: when I run 'java -cp = /home/ec2-user/code/jedis-2.0.0.jar first_try' , I get 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /home/ec2-user/code/jedis-2/0/0/jar'

Comment: `java -cp .: /home/ec2-user/code/jedis-2.0.0.jar first_try`

Comment: I get the exact same error when running that..

Comment: Are you sure there is only a single jar dependency.?

Comment: I think so, at the top of the file I have this: 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.Pipeline;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building your class path env var but then you don't use the value in your java command. You need $CLASSPATH instead of the dot after -classpath
Good luck learning java, I have enjoyed using it for over 10 years now ;)

Comment: Oh just noticed the javac - you may have to pass classpath to that too - don't use javac much now , what with eclipse and ant etc!

Comment: Thanks for the answer David.  I tried running the command "java -classpath $CLASSPATH first_try" and still go the same error, but intrestingly unlike the above error it did not mention the external jar but instead mentioned the file I was trying to run 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: first_try'

Comment: I use eclipse on my laptop(and it works fine) but I am trying to run this on a different machine(its a linux server)

Comment: when I do 'javac -classpath=$CLASSPATH first_try.java ' I get an error 'javac: invalid flag: -classpath=./jedis-2.0.0.jar'

Comment: There should be no equals sign - you need: -classpath $CLASSPATH

Comment: ^^^ on the javac line. The reason your "java" didn't work is that your first_try class hasn't been compiled because the javac line has failed

Comment: You need to get the javac to work before you can run the java line. I take it you have the .jar file in the current directory, and it is named correctly? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David. I tried not using the equal sign and it worked(and unlike before didn't give me any warns). I did a echo $? and it is successful but when I run 'java -classpath $CLASSPATH first_try' I get the same error.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: first_try   I even wiped out my server and did this from scratch.  Just installed java devel and jave runtime.

Comment: Getting closer - you will need to tack "." onto your classpath for the java command to pickup your compiled class files. So CLASSPATH should be .:./jedis-2.0.0.jar

Comment: WOW! It worked! System.out.println("Thank you!"*100); (untested :-)  It works and I'll play around with it more. So, just so I am clear, I had two problems with classpaths, one was finding the jedis jar file and the other was finding the complied first_try class file?

Comment: Yes, thats about it. You need a classpath for the compiler (javac) to pickup your external jar, then you need a classpath for the runtime (java) to pickup your class and any external jar it depends on. Enjoy your Java-ing ;]

Comment: Thanks again so much David! You rock!